# Laravel 4: Better way to create an array from an object than this

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

So I've retrieved an object from angular and need to convert it to an array.

The below works but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner or more efficient way to do this with Laravel:

```
$array = array();
foreach($input as $i){
    $array[] = $i['brand_name'];
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it in one line:**

```
$array = array_only($input, array('brand_name'));
```

if you need more than one value:

$`array = array_only($input, array('brand_name', 'address'));`

Comment: I believe an even simpler method would be typecasting. `$array = (array) $input;` This would convert the entire object into an array. (You can also do it the other way around `$object = (object) $array;`